# Richfaces inputNumberSpinner space between label

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a `<h:inputText/>` and a `<rich:inputNumberSpinner/>`next to each other but the input for the spinner has a huge space between the `<h:outputLabel/>` and the spinner. image below demonstrates what I mean, how can I fix this?

Regards.`

[image: hours]

Comment: I have tried moving then further apart but it keeps the space.

Comment: This is CSS issue, not jsf

Answer (score 0):

found a solution:

```
style="display: inherit !important"
```